# Prove there are not timelike vectors contained in the tangent bundle of a Cauchy surface

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, causality, singularities

Intuitively, I do not visualize how could it can contain temporary vectors. I imagine that if there were a timelike vector tangent to a [Cauchy hypersurface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface) $S$, you could consider an integral curve tangent at that point and deform it to get a causal curve that intersects S at two points, which would be a contradiction.

I can't formalize this idea and I haven't found this result in the literature, and that's why I ask it here.

Answer (score 1):

If the spacetime $\mathcal{M}$ admits a 3+1 split, it is called **globally hyperbolic**, and can be represented as (is diffeomorphic to) the sum of non-intersecting 3-manifolds:

$$ \mathcal{M} = \bigcup_{t\in \mathbb{R}} \Sigma_{t},$$

where the parameter $t$ is called coordinate time, and identified with the values of the codomain of the mapping (**time function**) $t: \mathcal{M}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

The pre-image of the mapping $t$ is a spatial hypersurface:
$$t^{-1}({t_{0}}) = \Sigma_{t_{0}} \subset \mathcal{M}$$

There is a result in the literature that (assuming some smoothness criterion) each Cauchy hypersurface is diffeomorphic, so the 3+1 splitting can also be written:

$$ \mathcal{M} = \mathbb{R} \times \Sigma $$

In a somewhat clearer presentation manner, the above formalities can be found in the second section of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9706046).

Now, we assume that the gradient of $t$ is non-vanishing.
It is a standard result in differential geometry, that when you have a parametrization of a submanifold as the pre-images of a mapping, like our $t: \mathcal{M}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the space tangent to this submanifold lies in the kernel of the gradient of the mapping, in other words:

$$ \Sigma_{t_{0}} = t^{-1}(t_{0}) $$

$$ \Sigma_{t_{0}} =  \text{ker}\;dt_{t^{-1}({t_{0}})}$$

Let me recall the motivation for that. Remember that if the pre-image of $t$ defines a submanifold, the tangent vectors to the submanifold cannot *point out of* the submanifold:

Let us work, somewhat informally, in the vicinity of a point $p$, which lies on the $\Sigma_{t_{0}}$ hypersurface, with  $t(p) = t_{0}$.

Moving away from the point, along the vector $v$
$$ p\prime = p + \epsilon v$$

And evaluating the time coordinate (whether it lies on the same submanifold, characterised by $t^{-1}({t_{0}})$.
$$ t(p\prime ) = t( p + \epsilon v) = t(p) + \epsilon\,dt(v)$$

If the $dt(v) = 0$, it follows that $v \in T_{p}\mathcal{M}$ indeed does not point out of the submanifold, as we obtain:
$$  t(p\prime )  = t(p) = t_{0}$$

and we remain in the same submanifold, with $v \in T_{p}\Sigma$.

Since
$$ 0 = dt(v) = \nabla_{\mu}t v^{\mu} = g_{\mu\nu}\,\nabla^{\mu}t v^{\mu}, \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
we see that the vectors tangent to submanifolds are orthogonal to the **normal vector field** $n^{\mu} \sim g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\nu}t $

Now, to continue on, the gradient of the time function $t$ is assumed to be time-like, therefore (I'm using the $(-,+,+,+)$ convention):

$$ \nabla_{\mu}t \nabla^{\mu}t < 0 $$

Now, we can seek the help of another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631690/prove-that-the-dot-product-of-two-timelike-vectors-cannot-be-0), where it is stated that the dot product of two timelike vectors cannot be $0$. Now, finally, by combining \eqref{eq1}, which states that the dot product of tangent vectors and the (time-like) normal vector is zero, and the aforementioned fact, the vector fields tangent to the hypersurfaces $\Sigma_{t}$ cannot be time-like.

As a final remark, I personally very much like the exposition to the 3+1 split as given by Eric Gourgoulhon in his [script](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0703035). All the above things might be (and almost certainly are) explained better there.